# why findByIdAndUpdate() function is not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose, next.js

I am working on the hotel project and here this function is not working.
I have checked fully req.query.id and req.body is passing its value. it does not return any error but it simply doesn't work

```
import Room from "../models/Rooms";
room = await Room.findByIdAndUpdate(req.query.id, req.body, ({
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
    }));
```

note:
typeof(req.body) returns a string and when I try to convert it into an array using JSON.parse it returns the error

```
{
    "error": "Unexpected token } in JSON at position 54",
    "success": false
}
```

```
req.query.id: 60c0582ca7a06d54682a7a4b
req.query.body: {
    "pricePerNight":1000,
    "internet": false,
}
```

Comment: can you show us req.query.id, and req.body

Comment: yaa sure, I have updated them in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$set`  to update the document. You cannot directly use request to update.

example,

```
await Room.findByIdAndUpdate(req.query.id, {$set:req.body}, {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
    });
```

It seems like your query is not valid. Make sure that valid object.

Comment: I tested and I will paste here you can refer this https://mongoplayground.net/p/QoNw_U6JVTD

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are making the post request like this

```
fetch(url,{
     method: 'POST'
     headers:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
     body: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

and then pares the body with **JSON.parse()**.
and if you are using express make sure you are using the **express.json()** middleware  like this

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
```

Comment: and try using the findByIdAndUpdate() method like this  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-findbyidandupdate-function/

Comment: hey I am right now  making a post request with postman, and I am using next.js so cannot use express instead I am using next-connect

Comment: for the body, try not using JSON.parse I think next-connect does that for you